# Creating a grid that get's redrawn on each zoom level

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I am trying to create a grid that gets redrawn on each zoom/pan level so that it covers only the currently-viewable-screen area.

How the grids and scroll-zoom-to-mouse-position work:

- Each zoomIn or zoomOut draws a grid based on the currently-viewable area (using [paper.view.bounds](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#bounds) as argument for where to start drawing the grid and how many cells are needed)
- I also delete any previously placed grid on each zoomIn/Out before creating a new grid.

It's a concept of dynamic grid which greatly improves performance since having a very large static grid has a huge performance hit. Therefore the grid only covers the currently-viewable screen area.

The issue is that the grids are *not relatively* positioned between them.

- The zoom homes-in on the mouse position thus it changes the
  [paper.view.bounds](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#bounds) object. Unfortunately the Grid-Drawing function also uses that object to   draw the grid, thus the grids are not positioned relative to each other.
- If I draw a rectangle on zoom level 1 and then I zoom in/out the
  rectangle is no longer aligned to the grid, since the grid was placed
  at a relatively wrong position with the previous grid.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for paperjs question on SO. Hope many will follow this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Alex's answer might be more correct,

I have figured out this solution where I create the grid at an xPos/yPos that will definitely correspond to a gridLine placement.

So `yPos/xPos` have now a `correctedBoundingRectLeft` and a `correctedBoundingRectTop` to draw their calculations from

The code:

```
var drawGrid = function(boundingRect, cellSize) {
  var vCellsNum = boundingRect.height / cellSize;
  var hCellsNum = boundingRect.width / cellSize;

  for (var i = 0; i <= hCellsNum; i++) {
    var offsetXPos = Math.ceil(boundingRect.left / cellSize) * cellSize;
    var xPos = offsetXPos + i * cellSize;
    var topPoint = new paper.Point(xPos, boundingRect.top);
    var bottomPoint = new paper.Point(xPos, boundingRect.bottom);
    var line = new paper.Path.Line(topPoint, bottomPoint);

    line.strokeColor = '#968d8d';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= vCellsNum; i++) {
    var offsetYPos = Math.ceil(boundingRect.top / cellSize) * cellSize;
    var yPos = offsetYPos + i * cellSize;
    var leftPoint = new paper.Point(boundingRect.left, yPos);
    var rightPoint = new paper.Point(boundingRect.right, yPos);
    var line = new paper.Path.Line(leftPoint, rightPoint);

    line.strokeColor = '#968d8d';
  }
}

// where `30` is the cell width/height in px
drawGrid(paper.view.bounds, 30);
```

And a [Paper Sketch for the above](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `drawGrid()` function will always begin from point (0,0). Instead, you should pass a point as an argument that offsets the grid by the appropriate amount.

Comment: I have revised the question to make it more clear and include a JSFiddle. If what you are saying still applies how would I go about offsetting the grid?